# How remove default module in fuel cms

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, fuelcms

[I want to remove all the module in the red box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx1yw.png)

I login using admin login, the default login given by fuel cms.
How to remove the default module that has been provided in admin login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing will not be an good option instead you can hide them

**To hide go to**

```
fuel/application/config/MY_fuel_modules.php
```

and add one line as follow for each module you want to hide .

```
$config['module_overwrites']['module_name']['hidden'] = TRUE;
```

> Example:

```
$config['module_overwrites']['pages']['hidden'] = TRUE; //to hide page module
$config['module_overwrites']['assets']['hidden'] = TRUE; //to hide assets module
```